# Maven reimport sets language level

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have simple Maven Java project in IntelliJ. I'm using Java 8 in my project and I set language level to 8. Why maven reimport sets language level back to 5? How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Java version explicitly to 1.8 in your project pom.xml like below

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```